# Removing duplicates in google sheets

Tags: join, google-sheets, duplicates, unique

I have a sheet with words in one column

- w1
- w2
- w3, w2
- w1, w2
- w1
- w1

I would like to have a column of words without doubles
`=JOIN(",",A1:A6)`(all in a row)
`=SUBSTITUTE(A8,", ",",")` (remove spaces)
`=SPLIT(A9,",")` (split to columns)
`=UNIQUE(A10:H10)` (remove duplicates). 
The `UNIQUE` command does not work, I still have the duplicates there (see https://docs.google.com/a/btlnet.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZTq6Xg1bm8w_dFBtnGKDR3Kvq86gmUw3W7SkpPYqw4g/edit?usp=sharing). Please help.

Comment: please share more code

Comment: We can't access your spreadsheet. Please fix permissions.

Comment: Ok, try this one https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ALy-qoldkM1rxiNd0T_Tp7Drk-lScjNKpetXPQOS-iw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  =UNIQUE(transpose(A10:H10))
```

`UNIQUE` only works with rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=UNIQUE(transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM((split(SUBSTITUTE(Join(",",A1:A6),",, ",","),",")) ))))
```